# How to resolve the underlying provider failed on open in wcf entity framework?

Tags: entity-framework

i am using my local system database connection string .The code is working fine.Then,
i placed my databse in another system and changed connection string properly.but i don't know why i am getting "the underlying provider failed on open" error.
anyone please tell me i given correct servername,username and password values in connectionstring.

Comment: Are you using distributed transactions ? May be a firewall issue.

Comment: i wrote services for getting information.Previously my local system database data is given .that database i placed in another system and try to accecc that service given "underlying provider exception".

Comment: Are you using SQL server? Can you connect to your new database using SQL server management studio?

Comment: This error means either connection string problem or permissions problem.

Comment: Permission problem means can u please clearly tell me .

Comment: How to give permission please any one tell me.